# what's the meaning of "std::function<void(int)>{}"

Tags: c++, std-function

I'm a new hand of C++. When I read source code of node.js, I saw these code:

```
struct StartExecutionCallbackInfo {
  v8::Local<v8::Object> process_object;
  v8::Local<v8::Function> native_require;
};

using StartExecutionCallback =
    std::function<v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Value>(const StartExecutionCallbackInfo&)>;

LoadEnvironment(env, StartExecutionCallback{});
```

My confusion is this one: `StartExecutionCallback{}`.

I think it can be interpreted like this:

```
std::function<v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Value>(const StartExecutionCallbackInfo&)>{};
```

But what does it mean? A null function pointer?

Comment: A default-initialized `std::function` object; the object that doesn't in fact hold any callable. A null object, if you will; it's indeed somewhat similar to a null function pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you probably know `StartExecutionCallback` is a **type** for a function [wrapper] object, accepting `const StartExecutionCallbackInfo&` as an argument, and returning a `v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Value>`.

Using `StartExecutionCallback{}` creates an **instance** of that type, but it's an instance that does not in fact contain any callable (i.e. the function wrapper has no target).
So yes, it is somewhat similar to a null function pointer.

`LoadEnvironment` that accepts this argument, can check whether it is an actual callable or an an empty one. Attempting to call an "empty" `std::function` will result in a [`std::bad_function_call`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bad_function_call) exception.

The code below demonstrates this (with a simplified version):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

//...

std::function<void(int)> f{};
if (f)
{
    f(4);
}
else
{
    std::cout << "f is empty\n";
}
```

The output will be:

```
f is empty
```

Comment: Is this one of the usage of "std::function"? 
I can't find document about "std::function" which explains this feature.

Comment: Yes, see an example here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/operator_bool.

Comment: I can't find any explaination about this syntax "std:function<>{}" in this document

Comment: Default initialization with `{}` is common in C++. For `std::function` it means an "empty" one. The link shows the specific meaning of an "empty" `std::function` object.